# roslaunch storage file creating/storing error

Tags: ros

while doing rosrun the storage file "storage.csv" is getting genrated and data is being stored but while doing roslaunch even the file "storage.csv" is not being generated. whenever I am doing roslaunch both the nodes are running but in subscriber the .csv file which I am trying to open is not opening. But whenever I do rosrun of the same node with talker and listener then my .csv file is getting generated and saved. please net me know is there is some other method to store the data during roslaunch because I have to use it in raspi 4 and even I want to know about why I am unable to open .csv file with roslaunch command is their some issue with my code or something else

**talker**

```
//header
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"

#include <sstream>

//main
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "talker_node");//talker node
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 1);//publisher
  ros::Rate loop_rate(10);//loop rate
  int count = 0;
  while (ros::ok())
  {
    std_msgs::String msg;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "hello world " << count; //output
    msg.data = ss.str();
    ROS_INFO("%s", msg.data.c_str());
    chatter_pub.publish(msg);//publish

    ros::spinOnce();

    loop_rate.sleep();

    ++count;
  }

  return 0;
}
// %EndTag(FULLTEXT)%
```

**listener**

```
//header
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

std::ofstream MyFile; // define object

//callback function
void storage_callback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    MyFile.open("storage_csv.csv",std::ios::app);//file open
    MyFile <<msg->data<<"\n";

         ROS_INFO("I recieve: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
                    MyFile.close();
}


//main
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "listener_node"); // creating node
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ROS_INFO("Storage code");

    
    MyFile.open("storage_csv.csv");//,std::ios::app);
    MyFile << "listner data."<<"\n";    
    MyFile.close();

ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe ("/chatter", 1, storage_callback);//subscriber

ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
//%end text%
```

**cmake update**

```
add_executable(talker1_executable src/talker.cpp)
target_link_libraries(talker1_executable ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(listener1_executable src/listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(listener1_executable ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

**launch file**

```
<launch>

<node name="takler_node" pkg="storage" type="talker1_executable" output="screen"/>
<node name="listener_node" pkg="storage" type="listener1_executable" output="screen"/>

</launch>
```

Comment: There are several issues with your code, like constantly opening and closing the file. If you want to continue debugging your talker/listener/csv node then I suggest looking what your nodes are actually doing when you launch your launch file. Eg `rostopic list/echo` `rosnode list/info`. 

All in all the problem of recording what is going on in ROS has been solved with http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag . There are ways to massage topics to csv if that is what you wish. https://answers.ros.org/question/55037/is-there-a-way-to-save-all-rosbag-data-into-a-csv-or-text-file/?answer=55046#post-id-55046